# OpenLayers2, trouble with XYZ layer bounds

Tags: openlayers-2, xyz

I have folder with image at server:
ex: /folder/zoomlevel(z)/id/x-y.png

I added it by the OpenLayer.Layer.XYZ with my getURL() function:

```
getUrl: function(bounds) {
  var xyz = this.getXYZ(bounds);
  var path = this.url + '/img_folder/' + z + '/';
  ...
  return path;
}
```

But there are 404 requests to generated URL, when I drag map to region without image.

How I can set minExtent or maxExtent for  this solution?